# Ansible: the local .ansible folder is created with root as it's owner (permission errors)

Tags: permissions

I installed ansible from its [installation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installation-guide) guide, but it creates a .ansible folder in the home directory of my user and when I would like to run a simple test command I give this error:

```
[ERROR]: Unable to set correct type for configuration entry for DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP: Unable to
create local directories(/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp): [Errno 13] Permission denied:
'/home/myuser/.ansible/tmp'
```

ERROR! Invalid configuration settings

How I can fix this?

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this? I think I'm running into this as well.

Comment: I removed ansible and all of its files (.ansible, python lib files), after reinstallation, it worked well.